# White line appears around windows after driver update

Tags: drivers

I tried to update the video drivers on my IBM thinkpad t42 but now there is a white line around my windows.  It is a small white line about 1 pixel wide. The line appears when I open a new windows or change tabs in a window.  If I click on the line it will disappear.
When I tried to take a screen shot of the line it disappeared.  XVidCap does not show the white line either. The white line only appears when windows are full screened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing.

In terminal write `sudo apt-get upgrade`, this should fix it.

Comment: do you mean `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: oh sorry yes i mean sudo apt-get upgrade :)

Comment: ok I am running that command now

Comment: that command didn't work,  When I go to update manager it says there are updates that can't be installed. The updates are under the (LP-PPA-xorg-edgers)